# How to get DefaultValue of column from database schema in C#?

Tags: c#, database-schema, datacolumn

I'm trying to read information from my database schema in C# (.NET 4.5, SQL Server 2014). I was having trouble with some fields such as MaxLength/ColumnLength until I [found a forum](http://www.databaseforum.info/25/561017.aspx) that mentioned setting the `DataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction` to `MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey`. Unfortunately the DefaultValue field is still blank even for columns that have a default set in the "Default Value or Binding" in the Column Properties in SQL Server.

```
SqlDataAdapter dbadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SELECT_STRING, CONN_STRING);
dbadapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
dbadapter.Fill(tbl);

// I actually looped through all rows/columns, but the net effect here is...
tbl.Columns[0].DefaultValue; // blank for all columns

// Also tried accessing the schema table available through DataReader
IDataReader reader = tbl.CreateDataReader();
DataTable schemaTbl = reader.GetSchemaTable();
/*
 * There are different schema fields here than in DataColumn,
 * but DefaultValue still blank. I looped through them all but...
 */
schemaTbl.Rows[0]["DefaultValue"]; // blank for all columns
```

How can I read the default value from a column in my table using .NET (preferably without resorting to querying SQL's `sys.*` tables).

**Clarification**

When creating or altering a table, you can set a default value of a column if none is provided. I'm trying to get the default value.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    Id int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    HomeState varchar(2) DEFAULT 'NY'
)
```

Now if I say, `INSERT INTO Person (Id, LastName, FirstName) VALUES (1, 'Doe', 'John')` the HomeState will be 'NY' even though I didn't set it.

Comment: Just confirming are you trying to get the default value for a column that is set in the database table ? like for a bit datatype it's (0) ?

Comment: @Searching When creating or altering a table, you can set a default value for a column. For example, I can say if a new row is created, to always set a datetime field to '1900-01-01' if no value is specified in the INSERT statement. Updated question with example.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know and seems like you've found your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo library as below:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
    var serverConnection = new ServerConnection(connection);
    var server = new Server(serverConnection);
    var database = server.Databases["databaseName"];
    var table = database.Tables["tableName"];

    foreach (Column column in table.Columns)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{column.Name} - default constraint: {column.DefaultConstraint?.Text ?? "None"}");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Crowcoder who suggested the below simplification:

```
var serverConnection = new ServerConnection("serverName", "username", "password");
var server = new Server(serverConnection);
var database = server.Databases["databaseName"];
var table = database.Tables["tableName"];

foreach (Column column in table.Columns)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{column.Name} - default constraint: {column.DefaultConstraint?.Text ?? "None"}");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: That works. It even gets dynamic values such as "GETDATE()" or "NEWID()". It's an odd way of working with the DB. If given a connection string, I'm already asking to connect to a specific DB (not a server), so why the need to move from serverConnection to server to database?

Comment: If you have rights you can just do `Server svr = new Server("your_server_name");`

Comment: I wasn't aware you could create a server instance from a database name @Crowcoder - thanks. Presumably this would have to be fully qualified, I.e. [server].[database]

Comment: No, was typo, I fixed it. Server name, not database name.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I'll test and update my answer if it works

Comment: Just a note to future readers, this code sample requires a reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo` as well as `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo`